# Batch file: How to save/use subdir-name when iterating thru directories with FOR /R {directory} in (.fileext)

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to unrar files with a batchscript. I want to iterate thru a folder and its subfolders and whenever there is a .rar file I want it to rar its content into the same folder as the .rar file is in. 
I'm using unrar.exe to do this and it needs me to specify the output folder when raring. 
If I dont specify any folder it rars it to the "current folder", which is the folder for the batfile.

this is my code:

```
FOR /R %dir_of_file% %%X in (*.rar) do (

"%unrarexe_path%\unrar.exe" x -y -r %%X {set unrarfolder path}

)
```

Is there some way to in evry iteration in the for loop, save the path to the current subdirectory that I'm looking thru?

Something like:

```
set unrar_to_here={haxcommand that will give me current subdirectory in for-loop}
```

Hope my question is understandable:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?  Just make the current working directory the directory containing the rar file and extract to the current folder.  I'm not sure about the syntax of the unrar command though.  I leave that to you.  :)

```
FOR /R %dir_of_file% %%X in (*.rar) do (

    pushd "%%~dpX"
    "%unrarexe_path%\unrar.exe" x -y -r %%X
    popd

)
```

Comment: In a `for` loop, the `%%~xX` notation signifies special meaning.  In this case, `~dp` means the drive path of `%%X` (without the filename).  See the last couple of pages of `help for` for more info.  For what it's worth, `call` accepts similar syntax with its arguments -- and by extension, batch scripts as a whole do as well.  `%~f0` means the fully qualified path and name of the current running batch script, even if you didn't supply the path or the extension when you executed it.  See `help call` for more info.

Comment: @user2190459 - Uuhhh, ok, but you clicked someone else's check mark.

Comment: Ooops! sry, It's my first time on this site:) clicked it now!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It will put the files in the same folder as the archive:

```
@echo off &setlocal
FOR /R %dir_of_file% %%X in (*.rar) do (
    "%unrarexe_path%\unrar.exe" x -y -r "%%~X" "%%~dpX"
)
endlocal
```